# Range object default member issue

Tags: excel, vba

Microsoft documentation about the Range object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) says that "The default member of Range forwards calls without parameters to the Value property".

Since Range.Resize property returns a Range object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize), why the first line of code below doesn't work, but the second one does?

```
r(5).Resize(1, 3) = r(5).Offset(1).Resize(1, 3) 'It doesn't work (doesn't do anything)
r(5).Resize(1, 3).Value = r(5).Offset(1).Resize(1, 3).Value 'It works as expected
```

**EDIT**

I did some tests, and the issue pointed out seems to occur only with multiple cells ranges, as the sub below shows:

```
Sub MY_TEST()
    'SINGLE CELL RANGES - ALL FOUR FORMS BELOW WORK
    Range("A1") = Range("A2")
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A2")
    Range("A1") = Range("A2").Value
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A2").Value
    'MULTIPLE CELLS RANGES - THE TWO FORMS BELOW WORK
    Range("A1", "B1") = Range("A2", "B2").Value
    Range("A1", "B1").Value = Range("A2", "B2").Value
    'MULTIPLE CELLS RANGES - THE TWO FORMS BELOW DON'T WORK
    Range("A1", "B1") = Range("A2", "B2")
    Range("A1", "B1").Value = Range("A2", "B2")
End Sub
```

Comment: You shou us too little... What is `r` and how it was declared? Basically, the range `Value` places the range content in an array. Sometimes, VBA makes a guess regarding what you try accomplishing and considers the range as an array, without using `Value`. This is more often happening when you declare a variable as `Variant` and allocate the range to it. Anyhow, the correct/complete way of using it, is the second line you show us.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @FaneDuru. r(5) is the 5th item of r, which is a range object (dim r as Excel.Range). I would like to understand why the first line doesn't work as expected, since microsoft documentation says it should, and I try to avoid as much as possible to type code. I realize that r(5).Resize(1, 3) = r(5).Offset(1).Resize(1, 3).Value will work also, but why not the first version doesn't? :(

Comment: You have missed the part of the documentation relevant to your context _and calls with parameters to the `Item` member_ ; you _are_ using a parameter, so you have effectively bypassed the `Value` property (on first seeing your 1st line, I honestly thought that what was missing was the `Set` statement at the beginning - remember that some time in the future, someone will probably inherit your code, and it will be easier to explain if you _don't_ use default members)

Comment: Hello, @SpectralInstance. I did some tests, and the issue pointed out by me seems to occur only with multiple cells ranges, as the sub shows (I edited the question).

Answer (score 1):

This is odd - not an answer but more testing...

Start point:

```txt
     A    B
  ---------
1 |    
2 |  C    D
3 |  E    F
```

Step through this:

```vb
Sub Test2()

    Dim a, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ws.Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("A", "B")      'OK - get "A", "B"
    
    ws.Range("A1:B1").Value = ws.Range("A2:B2")    '? clears content from A1:B1 ?
    
    a = ws.Range("A2:B2")                         'using intermediate variable
    ws.Range("A1:B1").Value = a                   'works - A1:B1 are populated with "C", "D"
    
    ws.Range("A1:B1").Value = ws.Range("A3:B3")   '?  A1:B1 are cleared ?

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is odd. I would guess that VBA would internally always replace rg1 = rg2 with rg1.Value = rg2.Value before computing...